# Using models between an App and API app in Django Rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, active-model-serializers

I'm going to create API with Django Rest Framework for an existing Django project. I would like to use models of existing app *(**product/models.py**)* in *'**API/models.py**'*.
Will that work smoothly as of using models across multiple apps using
`from product.models import item,...`

After importing I'll be creating **serializers.py** .

Can anyone answer me whether this will work?

Comment: yes, that should work. Why not just try it and see, a simple test case?

Comment: Yes I tried and it worked

Comment: excellent! Django apps are designed to be modular, so you can reuse them elsewhere. This behavior is common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this works, we can import and use models of other apps in this way.